# do something when an instance becomes true in an each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am running jQuery's `.each` function on a button click that runs through three line items. When another object on the page is clicked one of the line items will receive a class of 'selected', it starts on the first line item as default.

I want to execute something when the `data-index` of the `li` is greater than 0 and that `li` has the class name of `selected`.

```js
const $orderStatusButton = $('form#oar-widget-orders-and-returns-form button');

$orderStatusButton.on('click', function() {
  $(".selectric-scroll ul li").each(function() {
    var DataIndex = $(this).data('index');
    console.log(DataIndex);
    if ((DataIndex > 0) && ($(this).hasClass('selected'))) {
      $('div#oar_select-error').css('display', 'none');
    } else {
      $('div#oar_select-error').css('display', 'block');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-index="0" class="selected"></li>
  <li data-index="1" class=""></li>
  <li data-index="2" class=""></li>
</ul>
```

Essentially, I want to hide a div when the line item with the `data-index` of 1 or 2 has the class name of `selected` and show it when the line item with the `data-index` of 0 has the class name `selected` and I'm not sure if I'm going about this correctly as it isn't working.

Comment: Class and index conditions aren't true in what is shown so not clear what exactly isn't working. Is the button in the form of `type="button"`? If not your form will submit

Comment: @jessica Are you trying to achieve something like [tabs](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp)

Comment: @charlietfl when another object on the page is clicked the class 'selected' moves to either the second or third <li> depending on which item is clicked, it is then that I want to hide the div when the '$orderStatusButton' is clicked.

Comment: You haven't confirmed if the form is getting submitted and page is reloading or not

Comment: @charlietfl sorry, no the form is not getting submitted

Comment: Then you really need to provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: No need to use `.each()` you can just use the selector like @F Lins said.. `if($(".selectric-scroll ul li.selected").data('index') > 0){ //hide }else{ //show}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are looping through all elements you'll always end up with the display value of the last iteration of the each function.
What you should probably be doing is using the selected class on your jquery selector:

```
$(".selectric-scroll ul li.selected")
```

then you only have to process one element on the each function.

Comment: Every time you run the onClick the selector will be processed again and retrieve the element currently selected

Comment: thank you , something small I overlooked, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `toggleClass("someclass")` and add CSS

```
li.someclass { 
display:none;
OR
visibility:hidden;
};
```